# Python: fill column based on first charakter of another columns content

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe looking like this:

```
+-----+------+
| No  | type |
+-----+------+
| 123 | C01  |
| 123 | C02  |
| 123 | T01  |
| 345 | C01  |
| 345 | H12  |
| 345 | H22  |
+-----+------+
```

and a numpy array like this:

```
arr = [Car, Tree, House]
```

Desired output:

```
+-----+------+----------+
| No  | type | category |
+-----+------+----------+
| 123 | C01  | Car      |
| 123 | C02  | Car      |
| 123 | T01  | Tree     |
| 345 | C01  | Car      |
| 345 | H12  | House    |
| 345 | H22  | House    |
+-----+------+----------+
```

So I would like to add a column containing the element of the arr, where the first charakter matches to the first charakter of column type.

There is ony one element within the array for each first charakter.

What is the best way to achieve this? I could do this manually for each first charakter but I would like to do this within one run e.g. with apply-function.

Thank you,

MaMo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
No  type
123 C01
123 C02
123 T01
345 C01
345 H12
345 H22'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data),sep='\s+')

arr = ['Car', 'Tree', 'House']
d = {x[0]:x for x in arr}                   # Create a map
df['category'] = df['type'].str[0].map(d)   # Apply map to str[0]
```

Results in:

```
    No type category
0  123  C01      Car
1  123  C02      Car
2  123  T01     Tree
3  345  C01      Car
4  345  H12    House
5  345  H22    House
```

**Explanation**:

1. Create dictionary by first values of `arr`
2. Select first value of `type` column by `str[0]` and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`

Comment: @Anton vBR - Thank you for sample.

Comment: @MaMo - Glad can help!